# remove shipping and billing from woocommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates

I want to remove the billing address and shipping address from the admin-new-order.php. I already have a duplicate of it in my theme. I was able to remove the email and phone number, but I just cant remove the billing and shipping.

To remove the email and phone I did this

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields' );    
function custom_woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields( $totals ) {
      unset( 
             $totals['billing_email'],
             $totals['billing_phone']
            );
           return $totals;   
         }
```

I know that if I completely removed:

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

it would remove everything, but I can't do that because I need the notes, and delivery times (from a plugin) that displays there. If I delete the whole thing then it deletes everything.

I've tried

```
unset($totals['billing_first_name']);
```

And so many variations of this but it doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQSm6.jpg)

Comment: Please post var_dump() of all the variables in the action.

Comment: Its too long to post. It only allows like 600 characters here :/

Comment: Use https://giat.github.com or paatebin.com

Comment: I think I did this right. https://gist.github.com/frankymagana/601c6452df3e7be39f26369ad1b2b374

Answer (score 5):

In all email templates you have below do action hook. `WC_Emails::email_address()`  this function code is used for add billing and shipping details in mails.

```
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

For remove the billing and shipping detail from mail put bellow function in your `function.php` file

```
function removing_customer_details_in_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $wmail = WC()->mailer();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $wmail, 'email_addresses' ), 20, 3 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'removing_customer_details_in_emails', 5, 4 );
```

Comment: I tried adding this and it gave me a conflicting error with something else. So its not possible to remove shipping and billing with the "unset()" like I removed the email and phone?

Comment: @Franky this code is working fine. Please provide the error screen shot or more details.

Comment: Or even if I could just add the "Customer Notes" to the "meta" section, that would solve my problem.

Comment: how can i send a screenshot. My comment was deleted by stackoverflow

Comment: @Franky edit your question and upload you screenshot. or upload image in other third party server and share links of image

Comment: I followed. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/ to create that plugin to add a second email sent. Your code conflicts with this

I can't add any code to functions.php because it'll overide all emails. And I only need this to overide admin-new-order.php. Thanks